# Microsoft's url for the Exchange powershell schema is not valid anymore

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to create a remote connection to an exchange Powershell hosted on IIS 8.5 - Windows Server 2012 R2.

Here's my code :

```
var connInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
            new Uri("https://xxx/PowerShell"),
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
            credentials);
```

It look like the Microsoft's Schemas url is not valid anymore. If I navigate to http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange, I have this :

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

And when I try to open my connection, I have this error :

```
Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client received an HTTP bad request status (400), but the remote service did not include any other information about the cause of the failure.
```

Is it possible the url changed ? I trid to find a topic about it, but I found no trace of a change...

Comment: that uri is valid, but visiting it doesn't work, used it for remote powershell access. Make sure it starts with http and not https.

Answer (score 2):

The schema uri doesn't have to be 'valid' in the sense you don't have to be able to navigate to it.  I know I'm not explaining it properly but it's more a reference than a valid location.

The error you're receiving is actually referring to the uri you have for your Exchange Server.  If you aren't connecting to an Exchange Server the connection will error.